# How to efficiently grow the size of the test data

Tags: java, sql-server, database

I have a database of approximately 100 auction sales. I want to create a tool that would grow my database to the size of lets say 10000 or 100000 sales. I need this for the testing purposes. I am using java and SQL Server 2005. Original data will come from a database backup file that would be restored and then manipulated to grow in size. What would be the most efficient way to grow the size of my data?

Comment: By efficient, do you mean fewest lines of code?  Or fastest way to enter large amounts of data?

Comment: you are asking to reduplicate data,please post some sample schema

Comment: Efficient for me would be fastest way to enter large amounts of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fast and quite easy way:

I start with a *mock-up* of your table with some existing data:

```
DECLARE @YourRealTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @YourRealTable VALUES
 ('One existing value 1'),('One existing value 2')
,('One existing value 3'),('One existing value 4');
```

--The following CTE will create up to 10^9 running numbers in microseconds...

--Lets insert ~4000 (4 exsiting times 1000)

```
DECLARE @start INT=1;
DECLARE @end INT  =1000;

WITH x AS(SELECT 1 AS N FROM(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS tbl(N))--10^1
,N3 AS (SELECT 1 AS N FROM x CROSS JOIN x AS N2 CROSS JOIN x N3) --10^3
,Tally AS(SELECT TOP(@end-@start +1) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) + @start -1 AS Nr FROM N3 
          CROSS JOIN N3 N6 CROSS JOIN N3 AS N9)
INSERT INTO @YourRealTable(SomeValue)
SELECT SomeValue
FROM @YourRealTable
CROSS APPLY Tally;
```

--And now be happy with ~4000 similare records:

```
SELECT * FROM @YourRealTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create some test data and make an sql script to insert this data.
You must then handle the keys etc. to have correct ids.
Then run the script and you're done.
Repeat if you need new or more data.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any identity columns, you can do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Sales
SELECT  
    S.*
FROM    
    Sales S
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 L UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5) Factor
```

Comment: I do have identity columns. Could I 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ' ?

Answer (score 0):

Use **While**:

```
DECLARE @Id INT=1

WHILE @Id<5
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Sales
    SELECT * FROM Sales
    SET @Id=@Id+1;      
END
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `set` with `insert`?

Comment: @talex those are 2 separate statements, not a single statement.